# How to show catgories name on woocommerce order emails Table list

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I want to show custom value on woocommerce order email. See this screen shot https://s.nimbus.everhelper.me/share/1115381/uotnwxg567yh8pnt0e9o   if any one know solutions then please inform me. How can i show custom value woocommerce order email.

Thanks,
Ketan.